# Comprehension of linear algebra notations and concepts

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, cross-product

There is a line of math, whose mechanics I'm unsure about: multiplying {1} times a vector...
In "Learning From Data" by Abu-Mostafa, Magdon-Ismail and Lin (1.1.2 A Simple Learning Model) (pg 7):

---

"To simplify the notation of the perceptron forumula, we will treat the bias b as a weight w<sub>0</sub> = b and merge it with the other weights into one vector w = [w<sub>0</sub>,w1<sub>1</sub>,...,w<sub>d</sub>]<sup>T</sup>, where <sup>T</sup> denotes the transpose of a vector, so w is a column vector.  We also treat x as a column vector and modify it to become x=[x<sub>0</sub>,x<sub>1</sub>,...,x<sub>d</sub>]<sup>T</sup>, where the added coordinate x<sub>0</sub> is fixed at x<sub>0</sub>=1.  Formally speaking, the input space is now:

χ = {1} x ℝ<sup>d</sup> = {[x<sub>0</sub>,x<sub>1</sub>,...,x<sub>d</sub>]<sup>T</sup> | x<sub>0</sub>=1, x<sub>1</sub> ∈ ℝ,..., x<sub>d</sub> ∈ ℝ }"

---

To explain what I think is going on here is an example with an arbitrary 3-dimensional vector A:
let A = [a<sub>0</sub>,a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>] where a<sub>0</sub> = 2.3, a<sub>1</sub>= 8, a<sub>2</sub> = 7.6, so...

```
χ = {1} x ℝ3 = [new vector with one more element that increases dimension to ℝ4 ?]
```

```
χ = {1} x A = [ 1,2.3,8,7.6] ?
```

I also encountered set theory which explained the Cartesian product/cross product of two sets... {1,2} x {3,4} = {(1,3),(1,4),(2,3),(2,4)} so I'm inferring that [a<sub>0</sub>,a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>] is a set of one element whose element is a vector and so, {1} x {[a<sub>0</sub>,a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>]} = {1, [a<sub>0</sub>,a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>]} or just {1,a<sub>0</sub>,a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>}?

Comment: You got it right, although some of your notation is not quite correct. For example, $\{1\}\times A$ does not make sense because $A$ is not a set. The last line is completely correct though.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D$ be the set of your original training data points. $D$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The procedure that you are describing is just constructing the Cartesian product of $\{1\} \times D$.

That is if $\begin{bmatrix} x_1, \ldots, x_n \end{bmatrix}^T \in D$, then we are constructing the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1, x_1, \ldots, x_n\end{bmatrix}^T.$

It is a common trick to first work with a version of the algorithms with no non-zero intercept and then visualize the problem with intercept as a problem without an intercept in a higher dimensional space since

$$b + \sum_{i=1}^n c_ix_i=\begin{bmatrix} b,  c_1, \ldots,c_n\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix} 1\\  x_1, \\ \vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix}$$